Base property's type on another property's value of the same type | Allow union of literals
In TypeScript, is it possible to base the union of allowed literals for an object's property on the value entered in another property (essentially referencing this instance of the type)?
A pseudo example of what I mean (I don't think TMethodKeys is relevant, but I included it just in case):
type TMethodKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any
        ? K
        : never;
}[keyof T];

// ---------------------

type OptionA = {
    aFunctionForOptionA: () => string;
    anotherFunctionForOptionA: () => number;
}

type OptionB = {
    thisIsAFunctionForOptionB: () => boolean;
    thisIsAnotherFunctionForOptionB: () => bigint;
}

type Base = {
    baseFunctionA: () => OptionA;
    baseFunctionB: () => OptionB;
}

type Objective = {
    baseKey: TMethodKeys<Base>;
    subKey: TMethodKeys<ReturnType<Base[Objective['baseKey']]>>; // I want the allowed union of literals of this property to be based on the "this" instance of `Objective` it's `baseKey`.
}

const Test = [
    {
        baseKey: 'baseFunctionA',
        subKey: '...' as never, // Because `baseKey` is `baseFunctionA`. This instance of `Objective` should allow for: `'aFunctionForOptionA' | 'anotherFunctionForOptionA'`
    },
    {
        baseKey: 'baseFunctionB',
        subKey: '...' as never, // Because `baseKey` is `baseFunctionB`. This instance of `Objective` should allow for: `'thisIsAFunctionForOptionB' | 'thisIsAnotherFunctionForOptionB'`
    },
] as const satisfies Objective[];

Similar to how the Event subtype for the ev parameter of the listener callback is based on what is entered on type:
interface Document {
    addEventListener<K extends keyof DocumentEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Document, ev: DocumentEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
}


We can use distributive conditionals to create a union of objects, essentially creating a discriminated union around the baseKey prop.
Essentially the type Objective becomes:
type Objective = {
    baseKey: "baseFunctionA";
    subKey: TMethodKeys<OptionA>;
} | {
    baseKey: "baseFunctionB";
    subKey: TMethodKeys<OptionB>;
}

Final code:
type TMethodKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any
    ? K
    : never;
}[keyof T];

// ---------------------

type OptionA = {
    aFunctionForOptionA: () => string;
    anotherFunctionForOptionA: () => number;
}

type OptionB = {
    thisIsAFunctionForOptionB: () => boolean;
    thisIsAnotherFunctionForOptionB: () => bigint;
}

type Base = {
    baseFunctionA: () => OptionA;
    baseFunctionB: () => OptionB;
}

// Use distributive conditional to create a union of objects
type Objective = TMethodKeys<Base> extends infer Key ? Key extends TMethodKeys<Base> ? {
    baseKey: Key;
    subKey: TMethodKeys<ReturnType<Base[Key]>>;
} : never : never;

const Test = [
    {
        baseKey: 'baseFunctionA',
        subKey: 'aFunctionForOptionA'
    },
    {
        baseKey: 'baseFunctionB',
        subKey: 'thisIsAnotherFunctionForOptionB',
    },
] as const satisfies Objective[];

Playgound
